# Joining two data sets and calculating different values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

So I have an Object of two arrays that I was trying to combine.

What I am essentially aiming to do is get the unique types from dataOne. I then need the total count of occurrences for each type. Then, I need to know for each type the total count of success and failed.

Then from dataTwo I need to include the number of clicks for each type.

At the moment I have the following which achieves this, although I am sure it can be tidied up.

```js
const ob = {
  "dataOne": [
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "failed"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "success"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 2",
      "name": "success"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 3",
      "name": "success"
    },
  ],
  "dataTwo": [
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "click",
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 2",
      "name": "click",
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 2",
      "name": "click",
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "click",
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 3",
      "name": "click",
    },
  ]
};

const dataOneReduced = ob.dataOne.reduce((acc, o) => {
  if (!acc[o.type]) {
    acc[o.type] = [
      {
        count: 0,
        success: 0,
        failed: 0,
        click: 0,
      },
    ];
  }

  acc[o.type][0]["count"] = (acc[o.type][0]["count"] || 0) + 1;
  acc[o.type][0][o.name] = acc[o.type][0][o.name] + 1;

  return acc;
}, {});

const result = ob.dataTwo.reduce((acc, o) => {
  acc[o.type][0][o.name] = acc[o.type][0][o.name] + 1;

  return acc;
}, dataOneReduced);

console.log(result);
```

What I am now trying to do is insert the success rate as a percentage.  So I need the output to be like so

```
{
  "Type 1": [
    {
      "count": 2,
      "success": 1,
      "failed": 1,
      "click": 2,
      "successPecentage": 50
    }
  ],
  "Type 2": [
    {
      "count": 1,
      "success": 1,
      "failed": 0,
      "click": 2,
      "successPecentage": 100
    }
  ],
  "Type 3": [
    {
      "count": 1,
      "success": 1,
      "failed": 0,
      "click": 1,
      "successPecentage": 100,
    }
  ]
}
```

How would I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: In the second `.reduce` (where the `result` is populated), please add this line: `acc[o.type][0].successPercentage = Math.round(acc[o.type][0].success / acc[o.type][0].count * 100);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1

You can loop over your object one more time and insert the percentage. It is not the best solution performance-wise, but it's simpler.

```js
const ob = {
  "dataOne": [
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "failed"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "success"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 2",
      "name": "success"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 3",
      "name": "success"
    },
  ],
  "dataTwo": [
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "click",
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 2",
      "name": "click",
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 2",
      "name": "click",
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "click",
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 3",
      "name": "click",
    },
  ]
};

const dataOneReduced = ob.dataOne.reduce((acc, o) => {
  if (!acc[o.type]) {
    acc[o.type] = [
      {
        count: 0,
        success: 0,
        failed: 0,
        click: 0,
      },
    ];
  }

  acc[o.type][0]["count"] = (acc[o.type][0]["count"] || 0) + 1;
  acc[o.type][0][o.name] = acc[o.type][0][o.name] + 1;

  return acc;
}, {});

const result = ob.dataTwo.reduce((acc, o) => {
  acc[o.type][0][o.name] = acc[o.type][0][o.name] + 1;

  return acc;
}, dataOneReduced);

for (const type of Object.keys(result)) {
  const obj = result[type][0];
  obj.successPercentage = obj.success / obj.count * 100;
}

console.log(result);
```

## Option 2

You can insert the calculation directly into `.reduce()`, and it will work fine because only the value will be overwritten with each iteration, and only the last, correct value will be in the output.

```js
const ob = {
  "dataOne": [
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "failed"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "success"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 2",
      "name": "success"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 3",
      "name": "success"
    },
  ],
  "dataTwo": [
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "click",
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 2",
      "name": "click",
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 2",
      "name": "click",
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "click",
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 3",
      "name": "click",
    },
  ]
};

const dataOneReduced = ob.dataOne.reduce((acc, o) => {
  if (!acc[o.type]) {
    acc[o.type] = [
      {
        count: 0,
        success: 0,
        failed: 0,
        click: 0,
      },
    ];
  }

  acc[o.type][0]["count"] = (acc[o.type][0]["count"] || 0) + 1;
  acc[o.type][0][o.name] = acc[o.type][0][o.name] + 1;
  acc[o.type][0].successPercentage = acc[o.type][0].success / acc[o.type][0].count * 100;

  return acc;
}, {});

const result = ob.dataTwo.reduce((acc, o) => {
  acc[o.type][0][o.name] = acc[o.type][0][o.name] + 1;

  return acc;
}, dataOneReduced);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The desired objective may be achieved by adding one line:
`acc[o.type][0].successPercentage = Math.round(acc[o.type][0].success / acc[o.type][0].count * 100);` as shown in below snippet

**Code Snippet**

```js
const ob = {
  "dataOne": [
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "failed"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "success"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 2",
      "name": "success"
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 3",
      "name": "success"
    },
  ],
  "dataTwo": [
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "click",
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 2",
      "name": "click",
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 2",
      "name": "click",
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 1",
      "name": "click",
    },
    {
      "type": "Type 3",
      "name": "click",
    },
  ]
};

const dataOneReduced = ob.dataOne.reduce((acc, o) => {
  if (!acc[o.type]) {
    acc[o.type] = [
      {
        count: 0,
        success: 0,
        failed: 0,
        click: 0,
      },
    ];
  }

  acc[o.type][0]["count"] = (acc[o.type][0]["count"] || 0) + 1;
  acc[o.type][0][o.name] = acc[o.type][0][o.name] + 1;

  return acc;
}, {});

const result = ob.dataTwo.reduce((acc, o) => {
  acc[o.type][0][o.name] = acc[o.type][0][o.name] + 1;
  acc[o.type][0].successPercentage = Math.round(acc[o.type][0].success / acc[o.type][0].count * 100);
  return acc;
}, dataOneReduced);

console.log(result);
```